# Improve performances of PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Since I've added the plugin WakaTime to my phpStorm (version 8) it slow download with huge delay.
For example, if I spell variable name wrong. it will show me that only after 5 seconds .. and that's a lot .. I didn't had this before the WakaTime. but the thing is that I can't remove that plugin, so I need to find a way to maybe make the PhpStorm to use more resources of the computer ? or anything else that could make it faster ?

I've pretty decent computer:

- RAM: **16 GB**
- OS: **Windows 10** (build 9879) x64
- Processor: **i7-4770K** (3.50GHz)
- GPU: GeForce **GTX 660**

Anyway to work this around ? by adding more memory and cpu limits ? or anything else ?

Comment: Are you using the latest plugin version? I can help more in the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/wakatime/jetbrains-wakatime/issues) of the project.

Comment: Converted it to a comment, since its not really an answer. When you do find out what's wrong, feel free to post that as an answer.